# How to read a data from a json and compare with the CSV and return the value using Python

Tags: python

How to read a data from a json and compare with CSV and return the value using Python

I have a Json as below.

***JSON***

```
{
    "request":  
        "title": {
            "Hotel": {
                "Choose hotel": [{
                    "value": "hotel 1"
                }],
            },
            "Place": {
                "Choose Place": [{
                    "value": "Place 1"
                }, {
                    "value": "Place 2"
                }, {
                    "value": "Place 3"
                }],
            },
            "Food": {
                "Choose food:": [{
                    "value": "Food 1"
                }],
            }
    }
}
```

**CSV**

```
title,question,options,assign
Hotel,Choose hotel,"hotel 1,hotel 2","tech1" 
Hotel,Choose hotel,"hotel 3,hotel 4","tech2" 
Place,Choose Place,"Place 1,Place 2","tech3" 
Place,Choose Place,"Place 3,Place 4","tech4" 
Food,Choose food,"Food 1,Food 2","tech5,tech6"
```

Any suggestions please.Need to search for the matching title,questions and value in csv file and return the tech..

I have tried the below script and it is not working. It is returning only the final value in the json

**Python**

```
import sys, argparse, csv, json

csv_file = 'test.csv'


for title in requestObj['request'].keys():
    for question in requestObj['request'][title].keys():
        fieldvalue=[]
        for tempvalue in requestObj['request'][title][question]:
            if isinstance(tempvalue,dict):
                Value=tempvalue['value']
                fieldvalue.append(Value)


def getArray(csv_file,assign,title,question,fieldvalue):
    applarray = []
    matched=False
    with open(csv_file, 'rt', encoding='ascii') as csvfile:
        for line in csvfile.readlines():
            csvArray = line.rstrip('\n' + '').split(',')
            if csvArray[0] == title and csvArray[1] == question:
                print("matcheddddd")
                for fv in fieldvalue:
                    if fv in csvArray[2]:
                        matched=True
                if matched==True:       
                    s=csvArray[assign]
                    emailadd = s.split(';')
                    emailadd = filter(bool,emailadd)
                    applarray.extend(emailadd)

        return applarray
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problem have you run into? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: You need to clarify what do you mean by "compare", e.g, what is being compared, the whole file or the value inside. If it is the value then do they need to be have the same index...

Comment: For example if we choose hotel 1 and place 2 it should assign tech1 and tech 3 . I have tried 



for t in Obj['title'].keys():

      title1=t

      for questions in Obj['title'][t].keys():

            fieldvalue1=questions

            fieldvalue2=[]

                  for tempvalue in Obj['title'][t][questions]:

                        if isinstance(tempvalue,dict):

                                VValue=tempvalue['value']

                                fieldvalue2.append(VValue)

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda overcomplicated but simple and straightforward nonetheless

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("foo.csv")
data = {'title': {'Hotel': {'Choose hotel': [{'value': 'hotel 1'}]},
  'Place': {'Choose Place': [{'value': 'Place 1'},
    {'value': 'Place 2'},
    {'value': 'Place 3'}]},
  'Food': {'Choose food': [{'value': 'Food 1'}]}}}

for _, v in data.items():
    for title, vv in v.items():
        for question, vvv in vv.items():
            for vvvv in vvv:
                for vvvvv, option in vvvv.items():
                    print(title, question, option, end=' -> ')
                    print(df.loc[(df['title'] == title) & (df['question'] == question) & (df['options'].str.find(option) != -1), 'assign'].values[0])
```

Output:

```
Hotel Choose hotel hotel 1 -> tech1
Place Choose Place Place 1 -> tech3
Place Choose Place Place 2 -> tech3
Place Choose Place Place 3 -> tech4
Food Choose food Food 1 -> tech5,tech6
```

Comment: Thank you. I have attached what i have tried. What is the issue in my script.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the script, it is returning only the final value in the JSON.

**Python**

```
import sys, argparse, csv, json

csv_file = 'test.csv'


for title in requestObj['request'].keys():
    for question in requestObj['request'][title].keys():
        fieldvalue=[]
        for tempvalue in requestObj['request'][title][question]:
            if isinstance(tempvalue,dict):
                Value=tempvalue['value']
                fieldvalue.append(Value)


def getArray(csv_file,assign,title,question,fieldvalue):
    applarray = []
    matched=False
    with open(csv_file, 'rt', encoding='ascii') as csvfile:
        for line in csvfile.readlines():
            csvArray = line.rstrip('\n' + '').split(',')
            if csvArray[0] == title and csvArray[1] == question:
                print("matcheddddd")
                for fv in fieldvalue:
                    if fv in csvArray[2]:
                        matched=True
                if matched==True:       
                    s=csvArray[assign]
                    emailadd = s.split(';')
                    emailadd = filter(bool,emailadd)
                    applarray.extend(emailadd)

        return applarray
```

It is not matching the records.
if csvArray[0] == title and csvArray[1] == question:
    print("matcheddddd")
Any help pls.